# MVC Edit View, JQuery change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an MVC view with the following jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myinput).change(function () {
            alert('Changed');
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I change the text in the 'myinput' box, I want the alert 'Changed' to be displayed.  This works fine... On the second change.  The first time the text is changed, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strange behaviour appears to be a bug in jQuery 1.4.1.  After upgrading to 1.4.2, the event worked as documented.

Answer (score 0):

try [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead of `change`